# Chrome Developers Tool appears mobile simulation

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

Why does when i enter developers mode. A mobile simulated app appears in my screen? like this?

https://gyazo.com/662477cac11bbc8a71cd3fc9630bcf47

Help me return this to original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can toggle between mobile view and web view by clicking this button on dev tools:

[image: dev tools mobile toggle button]